# Forge Viewer - Load second SVF and replace parts

Tags: javascript, autodesk-viewer

Is it possible to load second (or multiple) SVF file/s and then replace some parts of the old model with the loaded part?

For example: let's say that we have a chair with a default decoration like red back and i want to load .SVF file with green back only (not whole chair) and replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done.

Aggregation of multiple models is explained in this blog post for example: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/multi-model-refresher.

If you only want to load a specific set of objects from a model, you can do that by specifying their IDs to the `loadDocumentNode` method: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/minimizing-viewer-workloads-loading-models-partially-selected-components-and-features-only.

To hide an object from an already loaded model, you could for example use the [viewer.hide](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#hide-node-model) method (this would require disabling the "show ghosted elements" option in the viewer though). Alternatively, you could modify the fragments of this object to hide them or move them out of the camera view: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/working-2d-and-3d-scenes-and-geometry-forge-viewer.

Comment: Even though your answer is comprehensive, i still cannot find the solution. I am able to load more .SVF files, but they behave like they are not existing. They are in the view and i can see them, but i cannot see them in Model Browser. I tried to load it from your link (Model Refresher), but using Promise is throwing me an error for bad (json) response type. Maybe i am missing something, but the thing i want is just load a .SVF file and replace a part (component) with it.

Comment: I should noted that i am running localy and .SVF files are used by their relative paths (not URNs).

Comment: I see... serving the SVFs locally is not officially supported, and I think it's likely that the issues you're seeing (e.g., models not showing in the browser, promises throwing an error) are related to that.